Конфликт версий библиотек пайтон
У меня есть две библиотеки, и обе используют typing-extensions, но разных версий. Этот конфликт вызывает проблему, обе библиотеки необходимы в одном проекте. Как я могу решить эту проблему, не переписывая одну из библиотек? Я пытался заменить одну библиотеку, но для моих целей в Python доступна только одна.А другая - aiogram необходима потому, что проект был написан  на нем.

Попробуйте установить обе библиотеки с помощью
pip install library1 library2 --use-feature=2020-resolver

